# Node api preflight failed in postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman

When calling API https://mywebsite.com/api/register through browser and it returns correct response from server as `{ "error": false, "message": "Hello World" }`
If we hit the same request from postman then it returns with some html content as Please enable JavaScript to view the page content.
Below is node side code:

```
var express = require("express");

var app = express();

var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var router = express.Router();

var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');

var cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', "extended": false }));

var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('key.pem');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('cert.pem');
var passphrase = 'testphrase';
var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate, passphrase:passphrase};

router.get("/", function (req, res) {

    res.json({ "error": false, "message": "Hello World" });

});
app.use('/api', router);
var server = https.createServer(credentials, app).listen(8080);
```

The api working through the browser but not with postman. What will be the possible errors? 
Please help. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how you could be using an https URL `https://mywebsite.com/api/register` with this server code which does NOT start an `https` server.  It starts an `http` server.  Which is wrong?  Your code in your question or the URL in your questoin?

Comment: https url is correct. Edited code in the question and added the https configuration.

Comment: Are you specifying port 8080 in the URL in both circumstances?

Comment: Actually https://mywebsite.com is redirected to the internal url https://internalurl.com:8080. And it uses the port, for example, https://internalurl.com:8080/api/register. So https://mywebsite.com/api/register is redirected to https://internalurl.com:8080/api/register.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved now. The problem is with the firewall and proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to define API for server

```
const api = require('./{your api path}/api');
// Set our api routes
app.use('/api', api);
```

Answer (score 0):

If that run in brower that means it is get request and you are getting json from node server . Set header in postman

check what header type use use . Use this may be you are using application/js , use application/json

[image]

You can also check what you request is sending from browser by inspect the request ctrl+shift+i and then in network . And then hit the request , now check in network what is header type and the request . You will know what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks Himanshu for the response. I tried this by adding headers in postman which are sending through the browser. But still is not working.